# Enter two integer and display the largest number using predefined function

Tags: c++

I already type the function but I can't get the output. Can anyone help me. It must use predefined function. My program is running but it have some errors so please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float largeNum (float a, float b)
{
    float largeNum;
    if(a>b)
    cout<<"a is larger";
    if(b>a)
    cout<<"b is larger";

    return (largeNum);
}

int main()
{
    float num1, num2;
    cout<<"Enter number";
    cin>>num1;
    cout<<"Enter number";
    cin>>num2;
    cout<<largeNum<< "is larger"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never call largeNum

Comment: [*cough*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float largeNum (float a, float b)
{
    if(a>b)
         return a;

    return b;
}

int main()
{
    float num1, num2;

    cout<<"Enter number";
    cin>>num1;
    cout<<"Enter number";
    cin>>num2;

    cout<<largeNum(num1, num2)<< "is larger"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you let the OP figure that out?

Comment: LogicStuff, I gave him one of possible solutions. He may change it

Comment: Vikramathithan, no problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code to below. You have not given any thing to largeNum, so you cannot return it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float largeNum(float a, float b)
{
    if (a > b)
        cout << "a is larger";
    if (b > a)
        cout << "b is larger";

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    float num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter number";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter number";
    cin >> num2;
    largeNum(num1, num2);

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    void largeNum(float a, float b) 
    {

        if (a > b)
        {
            cout << a << " larger";
        }
        if (b > a)
        {
            cout << b << " larger";

        }


    }

    int main()
    {
        float num1, num2;
        cout << "Enter number";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "Enter number";
        cin >> num2;
        largeNum(num1,num2);
        return 0;
    }
```

in your code you just define the function but you are not calling this function main so thats why u get error